# allow login with domain forwarding/masking - Browser Issue

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, iis

I have a client that has a domain registered through GoDaddy (e.g., `http://www.godaddysite.com`). He has the domain set to forward w/masking to a page on our servers (eg., `https://www.someuniversity.edu/someproject/loginpage.aspx`).

When on our network (a university network) I can navigate to his domain, the forwarding/masking works and I can log in without issue. However, anyone off the university network, when visiting the client's site, cannot log into the site. It forwards/masks as it should, accepts the user name and password but stays on the login page after the credentials are accepted. If they navigate directly to my site they have no issues.

I checked his GoDaddy settings and everything appears right. GoDaddy says it is our configuration that is causing the problem (not allowing a different domain mask the site). Is this true? Is there something I need to change in IIS to allow people to log in when they visit through the GoDaddy site?

**Update:**
Finally was able to test this offsite. This scenario ONLY happens in IE. So now it is a browser setting issue.

Comment: Once you log in, are you being redirected to an internal site that doesn't allow access outside of your University?

Comment: @AdrianWragg no, it's still publicly accessible

Comment: I'd use Fiddler or similar to trace the connection attempts from both locations. Also, check server logs to see if it's at least connecting. Past that, there's simply not enough information here to do anything other than randomly guess at what the answer is. :(

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this sort of problem is described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2013/09/17/simple-introduction-to-p3p-cookie-blocking-frame.aspx

If you change the IE Privacy Settings (Tools > Internet Options > Privacy) to `Accept All Cookies` does the problem go away? If so, then you need to set a `P3P` response header.